# How to get details about Vmmem activity?

Tags: windows, virtualization

Vmmem is using 30% CPU whereas docker desktop is not started and WSL is not activated
how to understand the cause of the activity ?

Comment: Well some VM obviously is running. Check with `wsl --list` and Hyper-V manager, if installed.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB. HyperV manager Showed DockerDestop was started despite I didn't configured it to start automatically. The Docker Wale command Icon wasn't even available.